# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in umbraco 4.8.1

Tags: umbraco

Due to performance issue , I have added the publishing code in thread.

My code is:

```
public void functionname()
{
----------------
------------
    try
     {
         HttpontextforMailSending gethttpcontextforpublish2 = new HttpontextforMailSending()
             {
                 HttpContextReference = HttpContext.Current,
                 courseDocument = shortCourseDocument,
                 createdUser = new User(0)
             };

         Thread t2 = new Thread(PublishDocument);
         t2.Start(gethttpcontextforpublish2);
      }
      catch { }
-------------
-----------
}

private void PublishDocument(object input)
{
     HttpontextforMailSending httpcontextformail = (HttpontextforMailSending)input;
     Document course = httpcontextformail.courseDocument;
     User createduser = httpcontextformail.createdUser;

     if (course != null && createduser != null)
     {
         course.Publish(createduser);
         umbraco.library.UpdateDocumentCache(course.Id);
     }
}

public class HttpontextforMailSending
{
    public HttpContext HttpContextReference { get; set; }       
    public Document courseDocument { get; set; }
    public User createdUser { get; set; }
}
```

But I get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error on "course.Publish(createduser);`

The Umbraco version is 4.8.1.

May be this error is due to `course.HttpContext`. It  has `null` value.

However when I set it as `course.HttpContext = httpcontextformail.HttpContextReference;` it shows a warning

"`umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web.document.HttpContext is obsolete. Do not use this. Get`httpContext`via regular ASP.Net methods instead`.

When I debug this code, I get `HttpContext` on `httpcontextformail.HttpContextReference`.

But after executing  `course.HttpContext = httpcontextformail.HttpContextReference;`, `course.HttpContext` still have null value.

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Can you expand a bit on how this code is being called? Is it being called from within Umbraco as an event listener, or are you trying to call it from a scheduled task?

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco expects to be used within a web request and therefore the API will not work if called outside of a web request in another application etc.

If you want to execute some something using the Umbraco API externally then you will need to use [Umbraco Base](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbraco-base) (or similar) so that the API has the needed HttpContext.

Umbraco Base is a RESTlike system for allowing the execution of queries or code via defined URLs within an Umbraco context.